# How to preg_match this in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match, match

How may I `preg_match` this in PHP?

```
$item[0] = <tr><td rowspan=2>07/07/2016 14:55</td><td>AC MENDES - Mendes/RJ</td><td><font color="000000">Postado depois do horário limite da agência</font></td></tr>
```

I've tried the code below, but it didn't work...

```
if(preg_match("@<td rowspan=[2]>(.*)</td><td>(.*)</td><td><FONT COLOR=\"[0-9A-F]{6}\">(.*)</font></td>@", $item[0], $d))
{
  echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not using regexes at all to parse html? I am sure there are html parsers out there that would make that job much easier.

Comment: @DanielBrunner, I've never heard of it, I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3554833).

Comment: I'd suggest [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: Also, a kind of a workaround in case you can afford it - https://ideone.com/e6YTRj. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, That second suggestion works great! Thank you so much! If you'd like you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a DOM with XPath to get all `TD` texts:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<tr><td rowspan=2>07/07/2016 14:55</td><td>AC MENDES - Mendes/RJ</td><td><font color="000000">Postado depois do horário limite da agência</font></td></tr>;
DATA;
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tds = $xpath->query('//td');
$res = array();
foreach($tds as $td) { 
   array_push($res, $td->nodeValue);
}
print_r($res);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/FjRIeN)

The `//td` will get all `td` nodes. You might also be using `'//text()'` XPath to just grab all text nodes.

Else, *if you know what you are doing*, you may add some temporary strings after each `<td>` node and then strip tags and explode right with the temporary string:

```
explode("###", strip_tags(str_replace("<td>", "<td>###", $s)))
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/e6YTRj)